# RavenDB Database Configuration

Tags: database, configuration, nosql, ravendb

How to configure the RavenDB database that can be capable to sending too many requests, or receiving too large a response?

By default, RavenDB will not allow operations that might compromise the stability of either the server or the client and a RavenDB session automatically enforces the following limitations:

1. If a page size value is not specified, the length of the results will be limited to 128 results. At the server side as well, there is a hard limit to the page size of 1,024 results.
2. The number of remote calls to the server per session is limited to 30.

I want to configure DocumentStore/DocumentSession in the client that it increase limitation of page size value and number of remote calls the server per session.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: Hi ayende, I want to configure DocumentStore/DocumentSession in the client that it increase limitation of  page size value and number of remote calls the server per session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the max page size with the `Raven/MaxPageSize` setting as described [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/administration/configuration). You can adjust the max number of session requests via `IDocumentStore.Conventions.MaxNumberOfRequestsPerSession`. However, a better approach is to architect your application such that you don't need large sessions. Instead, prefer to create sessions for small unit of work and dispose them. If a certain operation requires a large number of requests, batch them into groups of 1,024 or so.